Why does IOException or EOFException occur when using Bluecove(javax.bluetooth)?
I want to develop a bluetooth program using Java.
When Compiling this code, there are few problems.
(http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2010/01/08/connecting-to-bluetooth-devices-with-java/)
These exceptions only occur when connecting Samsung Galaxy S10 and ZFlip 4.
However, when using galaxy s8, there is no exception.
Please give me the solution to solve this problem.
Thx.
(I apoligize my English skills :( )


import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.bluetooth.DataElement;
import javax.bluetooth.DeviceClass;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryListener;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.ServiceRecord;
import javax.bluetooth.UUID;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.obex.ClientSession;
import javax.obex.HeaderSet;
import javax.obex.Operation;
import javax.obex.ResponseCodes;


public class OfficialTest implements DiscoveryListener{

    private static Object lock=new Object();
    public ArrayList<RemoteDevice> devices;

    public OfficialTest() {
        devices = new ArrayList<RemoteDevice>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OfficialTest listener =  new OfficialTest();

        try{
            LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
            DiscoveryAgent agent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();
            agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, listener);

            try {
                synchronized(lock){
                    lock.wait();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }


            System.out.println("Device Inquiry Completed. ");


            UUID[] uuidSet = new UUID[1];
            uuidSet[0]=new UUID(0x1105); //OBEX Object Push service

            int[] attrIDs =  new int[] {
                    0x0100 // Service name
            };

            for (RemoteDevice device : listener.devices) {
                agent.searchServices(
                        attrIDs,uuidSet,device,listener);


                try {
                    synchronized(lock){
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }


                System.out.println("Service search finished.");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass arg1) {
        String name;
        try {
            name = btDevice.getFriendlyName(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            name = btDevice.getBluetoothAddress();
        }

        devices.add(btDevice);
        System.out.println("device found: " + name);

    }

    @Override
    public void inquiryCompleted(int arg0) {
        synchronized(lock){
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void serviceSearchCompleted(int arg0, int arg1) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
        for (int i = 0; i < servRecord.length; i++) {
            String url = servRecord[i].getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false);
            if (url == null) {
                continue;
            }
            DataElement serviceName = servRecord[i].getAttributeValue(0x0100);
            if (serviceName != null) {
                System.out.println("service " + serviceName.getValue() + " found " + url);

                if(serviceName.getValue().equals("OBEX Object Push\0")){
                    sendMessageToDevice(url);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("service found " + url);
            }


        }
    }

    private static void sendMessageToDevice(String serverURL){
        try{
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverURL);

            ClientSession clientSession = (ClientSession) Connector.open(serverURL);
            HeaderSet hsConnectReply = clientSession.connect(null);
            if (hsConnectReply.getResponseCode() != ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_OK) {
                System.out.println("Failed to connect");
                return;
            }

            HeaderSet hsOperation = clientSession.createHeaderSet();
            hsOperation.setHeader(HeaderSet.NAME, "Hello.txt");
            hsOperation.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, "text");

            //Create PUT Operation
            Operation putOperation = clientSession.put(hsOperation);

            // Send some text to server
            byte data[] = "Hello World !!!".getBytes("iso-8859-1");
            OutputStream os = putOperation.openOutputStream();
            os.write(data);
            os.close();

            putOperation.close();

            clientSession.disconnect(null);

            clientSession.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

Some Errors Occur. There is always IOException or EOFException.
Here is Error code.
Connecting to btgoep://A82BB9E0ED8B:12;authenticate=false;encrypt=false;master=false
java.io.IOException: 
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft.send(Native Method)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft.connectionRfWrite(BluetoothStackMicrosoft.java:829)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothRFCommOutputStream.write(BluetoothRFCommOutputStream.java:84)
    at java.base/java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:124)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXSessionBase.writePacketWithFlags(OBEXSessionBase.java:183)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXSessionBase.writePacket(OBEXSessionBase.java:147)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXClientSessionImpl.disconnect(OBEXClientSessionImpl.java:143)
    at OfficialTest.sendMessageToDevice(OfficialTest.java:162)
    at OfficialTest.servicesDiscovered(OfficialTest.java:126)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft$4.runSearchServices(BluetoothStackMicrosoft.java:524)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.SearchServicesThread.run(SearchServicesThread.java:149)

java.io.EOFException: EOF while reading OBEX packet; received 0 form 3 expected
    at com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXUtils.readFully(OBEXUtils.java:73)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXUtils.readFully(OBEXUtils.java:44)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXSessionBase.readPacket(OBEXSessionBase.java:205)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.obex.OBEXClientSessionImpl.disconnect(OBEXClientSessionImpl.java:144)
    at MyDiscoveryListener.sendMessageToDevice(MyDiscoveryListener.java:168)
    at MyDiscoveryListener.servicesDiscovered(MyDiscoveryListener.java:131)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft$4.runSearchServices(BluetoothStackMicrosoft.java:524)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.SearchServicesThread.run(SearchServicesThread.java:149)


"Please give me the solution" isn't going to help. You might want to have a look at [ask] and need to realize that we may be able to help you spot errors, provide hints etc. but SO is not a code writing or code fixing service. Apart from that if it fails on some devices and works on others you might need to debug on the devices where it fails - which is something we can't do.
